# Make struct Hashable?

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift3, hashable

I'm trying to create a dictionary of the sort `[petInfo : UIImage]()` but I'm getting the error `Type 'petInfo' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'`. My petInfo struct is this:

```
struct petInfo {
    var petName: String
    var dbName: String
}
```

So I want to somehow make it hashable but none of its components are an integer which is what the `var hashValue: Int` requires. How can I make it conform to the protocol if none of its fields are integers? Can I use the `dbName` if I know it's going to be unique for all occurrences of this struct?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Simply return `dbName.hashValue` from your `hashValue` function. FYI - the hash value does not need to be unique. The requirement is that two objects that equate equal must also have the same hash value.

```
struct PetInfo: Hashable {
    var petName: String
    var dbName: String

    var hashValue: Int {
        return dbName.hashValue
    }

    static func == (lhs: PetInfo, rhs: PetInfo) -> Bool {
        return lhs.dbName == rhs.dbName && lhs.petName == rhs.petName
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh good to know! Do you mind explaining the `static func` thing you added please?

Comment: Hashable extends Equatable. See the documentation for the two protocols for a full explanation of the `==` function.

Answer (score 39):

As of Swift 5 `var hashValue:Int` has been deprecated in favour of `func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher)` (introduced in Swift 4.2), so to update the answer @rmaddy gave use:

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(dbName)
}
```

Comment: You should just say `hasher.combine(dbName)` since `String` already inherits from `Hashable`. Also, you need to implement the == operator, and "the components used for hashing must be the same as the components compared in your type’s == operator implementation", defined [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable/2995575-hash).

Comment: @jangelsb good point about `String` - updated. Not going to expand this answer on the `Hashable` protocol in general as it's really just an addendum to the original answer.

Comment: @jangelsb comment is gold! Implementing the `==` is absolutely necessary to get it work.