# Remove duplicated in a Struct Array

Tags: swift

I am filtering an array that can have a value where there are multiple Models of the same name, only they have different model numbers.

**Variables**

```
var modelArray = [model]()
```

**Struct**

```
struct model {
    var modelName = String();
    var modelNumber = String();
    var manufacturer = String();
    var phiTypeCode = String();
    var phiTypeDesc = String();
}
```

**Filter**

```
var filteredArray = self.modelArray.filter { $0.manufacturer.range(of: manufacturerVar, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
```

This produces the correct filtered Array, only due to the possibility of similar models with different model numbers, I am trying to remove duplicates from `filteredArray`.
Fairly new to swift I don't have a great deal of experience making the struct hashable to be able to use the suggested solutions.

Hopefully this is more clear

Comment: How are you saving the data? Where is the data coming from?

Comment: "I am getting duplicate values" It's easy to eliminate duplicate values, but what do you mean "I am getting"? You are _putting_ the duplicate values there. If you don't want them there, don't do that.

Comment: @JLanders On an unrelated note, does it make sense to have a model called `""`, manufactured by `""`, and with no phyType code or Desc?

Comment: As it stands, how is this not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153674/remove-duplicate-structs-in-array-based-on-struct-property-in-swift?rq=1 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does there exist within Swift's API an easy way to remove duplicate elements from an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/does-there-exist-within-swifts-api-an-easy-way-to-remove-duplicate-elements-fro)

Comment: @Hamish I did look at that solution, However fairly new to Swift, was having difficulty make my Struct Hashable to work in that solution

Comment: @JLanders There is [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33984316/2976878) to that linked Q&A which gives an example of conforming to `Hashable` – also see [Make struct Hashable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972319/make-struct-hashable) & [How to implement the Hashable Protocol in Swift for an Int array (a custom string struct)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31438210/2976878), which contains many useful links.

Comment: Making your own functionality to generate a unique data source if pretty easy, using `fast enumeration` or `mapping` plus conforming to protocol `Equatable`. See my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First off, I tried making a sample in my PlayGround.

1. Conform your model `model` to the protocal `Equatable`, like so:

   ```
   struct Car: Equatable {

       var modelName = String()
       var manufacturer = String()

       init(modelName: String, manufacturer: String) {
           self.modelName = modelName
           self.manufacturer = manufacturer
       }

       static func == (lhs: Car, rhs: Car) -> Bool {
           return lhs.modelName == rhs.modelName
       }
   }
   ```

In the code above, we're assuming that the `modelName` is the primary key of your model.

2. Now make a function that enumerates your data source and returns a new data source after checking the element one by one, like so:

   ```
   // returns unique array

   func unique(cars: [Car]) -> [Car] {

       var uniqueCars = [Car]()

       for car in cars {
           if !uniqueCars.contains(car) {
               uniqueCars.append(car)
           }
       }

       return uniqueCars
   }
   ```

Finally, you now have the function to generate a new unique data source.

Example:

```
// Variable

var cars = [Car]()

// Adding data models to data source

let car1 = Car(modelName: "Kia Picanto", manufacturer: "Kia")
let car2 = Car(modelName: "Honda XX", manufacturer: "Honda")
let car3 = Car(modelName: "Honda XX", manufacturer: "Honda")

cars.append(car1)
cars.append(car2)
cars.append(car3)

// Now contains only two elements.
let uniqueCars = unique(cars: cars)
```

Comment: This was perfect!!  Thank you for taking the time to detail this out

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. Now you can use the same function `contains` before adding an element to your data source. Good luck.